# Why don't these voxels I am drawing using GL.POINTS line up? How can I fix it?

Tags: webgl

I have been working on a voxel engine using webgl. It uses gl.points to draw voxels using a square based on your distance to the point.

Here is the basics of how it work

```
Vertex: 

//Get position using the projection matrix and block XYZ 
gl_Position =  uMatrix * uModelMatrix * vec4(aPixelPosition[0],-aPixelPosition[2],aPixelPosition[1],1.0);

//Set size of point based on screen height and divide it by depth to size based on distance
gl_PointSize = (uScreenSize[1]) / gl_Position[2];
```

And here is how that looks when it is from a non-problematic angle.

[image]

You can see, it looks just how I want to (of course its not as good as real cubes, but preforms amazing on mobile) now lets go inside of this hollow cube and see what it looks like. This picture is me looking into the corner

[image]

I changed the background color to highlight the issue. Basically if you are looking directly at the blocks, they work fine, but if they are at an angle to you, they are too small and leave large gaps. This picture is me looking at a wall directly

[image]

You can see facing the back wall works perfect, but all the other walls look bad.

So clearly I am doing something wrong, or not thinking about something properly. I have tried a lot of different things to try and repair it but none of my fixes work proper.

I have tried making it so blocks towards the edge of the screen are bigger, this fixes the problem but it also makes blocks bigger that don't need to be. Like for example looking at a flat wall, the edges would become much bigger even though  looking at a flat wall doesn't have the issue.

I have also tried making the squares much bigger and this fixes it but then they overlap everywhere and it doesn't look nearly as clean.

You can see the example of the problem here (just takes a second to generate the structure) 
 https://sebastian97.itch.io/voxel-glitchy
WASD- movement
Arrow keys / mouse - Look

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want to happen. For example [this point](https://imgur.com/Fo4V9rF) in order for it to fill to the left and right it needs to be about 2x in size but 2x in size will overlap a bunch with above and below.

Comment: Interesting observation and always happy to see you  on here gman  respect all you do for the community, I'm wondering if there is something I can do to make all my points line up in a grid properly .

Comment: Updated the original post with an example of the issue . If I have to have the ones looking at you from an angle be slightly overlapping that is way better than the gaps. Only the blocks you are directly looking at need to be in a uniform grid as long as the transition between the two isn't too jarring. Thanks again.

Comment: The top picture makes no sense to me. Points don't turn so how are making that image?

Comment: Should have mentioned, I turned it off in the example, but I have something setup so if you are looking down or up they rotate with your xRotation.

Comment: You can't rotate gl.POINTS

Comment: Rotated as in, the texture is rotated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your projection matrix separated out I think you want `gl_PointSize` to be

```
vec4 modelViewPosition = view * model * position;

gl_PointSize = someSize / -modelViewPosition.z;

gl_Position = projection * modelViewPosition;
```

```js
'use strict';

/* global window, twgl, requestAnimationFrame, document */

const height = 120;
const width = 30
const position = [];
const color = [];
const normal = [];
for (let z = 0; z < width; ++z) {
  for (let x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    position.push(x, 0, z);
    color.push(r(0.5), 1, r(0.5));
    normal.push(0, 1, 0);
  }
}
for (let y = 1; y < height ; ++y) {
  for (let x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
    position.push(x, -y, 0);
    color.push(0.6, 0.6, r(0.5));
    normal.push(0, 0, -1);
    
    position.push(x, -y, width - 1);
    color.push(0.6, 0.6, r(0.5));
    normal.push(0, 0, 1);
    
    position.push(0, -y, x);
    color.push(0.6, 0.6, r(0.5));
    normal.push(-1, 0, 0);
    
    position.push(width - 1, -y, x);
    color.push(0.6, 0.6, r(0.5));
    normal.push(1, 0, 0);
  }
}

function r(min, max) {
  if (max === undefined) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const v3 = twgl.v3;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec3 color;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelView;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_color;

void main() {
  vec4 modelViewPosition = modelView * position;
  gl_Position = projection * modelViewPosition;
  gl_PointSize = 850.0 / -modelViewPosition.z;
  v_normal = mat3(modelView) * normal;
  v_color = color;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec3 v_color;

void main() {
  vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vec3(1, 2, 3));  // arbitrary light direction
  
  float l = dot(lightDirection, normalize(v_normal)) * .5 + .5;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color * l, 1);
}
`;

// compile shader, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// make some vertex data
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  position,
  normal,
  color: { numComponents: 3, data: color },
});

const keys = [];
const eye = [10, 10, 55];
const target = [0, 0, 0];
const up = [0, 1, 0];
const speed = 50;

const kUp = 38;
const kDown = 40;
const kLeft = 37;
const kRight = 39;
const kForward = 87;
const kBackward = 83;
const kSlideLeft = 65;
const kSlideRight = 68;

const keyMove = new Map();
keyMove.set(kForward,    { ndx: 8, eye:  1, target: -1 });
keyMove.set(kBackward,   { ndx: 8, eye:  1, target:  1 });
keyMove.set(kSlideLeft,  { ndx: 0, eye:  1, target: -1 });
keyMove.set(kSlideRight, { ndx: 0, eye:  1, target:  1 });
keyMove.set(kLeft,       { ndx: 0, eye:  0, target: -1 });
keyMove.set(kRight,      { ndx: 0, eye:  0, target:  1 });
keyMove.set(kUp,         { ndx: 4, eye:  0, target: -1 });
keyMove.set(kDown,       { ndx: 4, eye:  0, target:  1 });

let then = 0;
function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds
  const deltaTime = time - then;
  then = time;
  
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  
  const fov = Math.PI * 0.25;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 1000;
  const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);
  
  const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);
  const modelView = m4.translate(view, [width / -2, 0, width / -2]);
  
  keyMove.forEach((move, key) => {
    if (keys[key]) {
      const dir = camera.slice(move.ndx, move.ndx + 3);
      const delta = v3.mulScalar(dir, deltaTime * speed * move.target);
     v3.add(target, delta, target);
   if (move.eye) {
     v3.add(eye, delta, eye);
      }    
    }
  });

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    projection,
    modelView,
  });  
  
  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo, gl.POINTS);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);

window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
#i { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 5px; font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<div id="i">ASWD ⬆️⬇️⬅️➡️</div>
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/bjTEM1g.png Using your example in full screen I get the same effect, but it seems like the gaps are a lot less large. I just translate my projection matrix to the camera's position each frame, and rotate to the cameras X & Y rotation. Would I need a view matrix to get closer results like yours? Thanks.